# What are some top secret hacks for people who are familiar with LaTeX?

Tags: emacs, vim, org-mode, tooltips

I have used LaTeX for 10 years. I read an introduction to LaTeX on the internet and started writing in LaTeX. With the time I got familiar with Tikz and other packages.

Today I learned about: org mode for Emacs. A game changer.

Any tips, tricks, secrets you would like to share with someone who knows the basics, use LaTeX day2day but is not an expert?

Comment: Well, `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are useful.  Actually, this question reminds me of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528262/are-there-any-dangerous-commands-in-latex

Comment: [latex3](https://ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel) and the `interface3` is interesting to  learn for me.

Comment: The fact that the source files are just plain text opens up a lot of possibilities people don't often consider. You can script it with literally *any* programming language, not just lua. I often embed php blocks into latex files, and pipe the php output into a latex compiler.

Comment: I could write an answer, but it's a secret.